# Looking for a monitor to fit in a 30 cm height place

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

I'm looking for a monitor for my desk, but I have one mayor restriction. I have only 30 cm of space between the desk and a window. I'm searching a monitor that fit in that height. I have been searching for a monitor with adjustable stand and for ultra-wide monitor with that height but I can't find anything.

Also, the monitor should:

- be at least 1080p (I think this shouldn't be a problem nowadays)
- have HDMI connection
- desirable USB-C connection

I prefer an ultra-wide monitor, so I can put away the laptop, but I don't really care. The most important thing is that it fits into the height I have.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! Any reason an aftermarket monitor arm wouldn't work? That should hopefully allow you to place it pretty much as low as you want.

Comment: The thing is that the monitor can’t be more than 30 cm height + that arm also can’t be more than 30 cm height. The limitation is because of the windows. If I get something higher the window can’t be opened. I’ll take a look to the arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LG's [29UM69G-B](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29UM69G-B-ultrawide-monitor) and [29UM59A-P](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29UM59A-P-ultrawide-monitor) are both 29" 2560x1080 ultrawides with USB-C and HDMI, with the 29UM69G-B apparently being the updated version. It's juusstt over the 30 cm mark at 32.8 cm without the stand; however, it still gets my recommendation as there are no other USB-C equipped ultrawides that are this small. Worst come to worst, you can strip the plastic housing off the monitor, which should hopefully get you a centimeter or two.

In terms of mounting, both monitors support a standard 75x75 VESA mount and weight only 5 kg, which is well supported by almost all monitor arms. Most monitor arms are shorter than the monitor when mounted level with the desk; here's an example of an adjustable arm set to a low position with a small monitor. Notice that the top of the arm is still below the top of the monitor, even though the monitor is below the top of the base (where the desk would be):
[image]

I recommend using [monitorarms.co](https://monitorarms.co) to find an arm that's within your budget and fits your mounting/look preferences. They have a convenient chooser, as well as well-documented specs for a ton of arms.